# Как правильно называть классы?

Tags: ооп, классы

Меня интересует не столько название, сколько расположение дополнительного слова, указывающего принадлежность к некому типу.
Для примера, если я создаю потомка класса **Model**, **Test**, то как будет правильно:

1. **TestModel**?
2. **ModelTest**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Правильно называть их по назначению выполняемых им действий, по существу имя не имеет привязки к предку. Но если того требует ясность, то предок должен указываться последним: ИмяКлассаИмяПредка.

Comment: Спасибо! Я помню, что давно читал о, не то чтобы конвенциях, больше это было похоже на пожелания, что имя расширяемого класса должен идти последним. А сегодня читал статью и там везде наоборот, что и побудило меня спросить.

Answer (score 2):

Безотносительно внетестовых конвенций: названиями XyzTest обычно обозначаются классы, которые содержат тесты для класса Xyz.

Answer (score 1):

Есть [Java naming convention](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html), согласно ей, название класса должно быть такое:

> Class names should be nouns, in mixed case with the first letter of each internal word capitalized. Try to keep your class names simple and descriptive. Use whole words-avoid acronyms and abbreviations (unless the abbreviation is much more widely used than the long form, such as URL or HTML).

Грубо говоря: имя класса должно быть существительным, если составное то в [CamelCase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case) и использовать только общепринятые сокращения.

При этом существуют и другие ограничения/соглашения. В частности имя `Test` обычно применяется разными тестировочными фреймворками, аннотациями и проч., поэтому это не является хорошей практикой применение этого слова.

Для составных имен общей практикой является применение практики: `[Child][Parent]`, например это хорошо иллюстрируется иерархией классов `java.io`:

```
InputStream
PipedInputStream
ByteArrayInputStream
```

Answer (score 0):

В стандартах разработки Ахарта (это ERP такая) прописано:

Предок_Потомок1_ПотомокПотомка1

Ну а как Вы будете называть свои классы зависит только от ваших предпочтений.

Мне все же кажется, что логичней предка как раз ставить в начало. Тогда в списке классов вся структура будет отображаться в одном месте по алфавиту.